# Run SQL query in shell script then sends output to email

Tags: linux, oracle, shell, unix, scripting

I need to execute a simple select count query in our oracle db. But this takes several hrs to complete. I want to do it using shell script so that I don't need to monitor every now and then if the query is still running  and want to send the output in my email since I only need the counts

I'm doing it in a remote server and don't have admin rights to disable the time limit before going disconnected.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Here is the initial code that I write.

```
     #!/bin/ksh
######################################################################
# File Name  : counts.sh
# Created    : 2019/27/19
# Author     :
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# $Revision: 1.0 $
# $Date: 2019/01/27 08:00:00 $
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Modification History:
# No      Date       Author         Note
#
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
#
########################################################################
DB_USERNAME=$1
DB_PASSWORD=$2
DB_DBASE=$3

#------------------------------------------------------------
# Start Log
#------------------------------------------------------------
DB_CONN=${DB_USERNAME}/${DB_PASSWORD}@${DB_DBASE}
LOG_DATETIME=`date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S`
LOG_FILE=/tmp/$LOG_DATETIME.log
EGREP=/bin/egrep
ORA_ERR_STR=ORA
#==Start Table Space ========================================
sqlplus -S ${DB_CONN} > $LOG_FILE << ORAEND

set serveroutput on;
set feedback off
SPOOL /tmp/counts.txt
PROMPT COUNTS

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM schema.db;

spool off;
ORAEND


mailx -s "Counts on $DB_DBASE is"  user@gmail.com < /tmp/counts.txt     
#===end of script=========#
```

I will call the shell script using nohup command.
Calling script: nohup ksh counts.sh user password DB &

Comment: I just only need the actual counts of the query.

Answer (score 2):

You never said what is result of that query. Yes, it *counts* something, but - how does the output look like? One value? One column in several rows? Many columns in one row? Many columns in even more rows?

As the query itself takes hours to complete, perhaps you'd want to be able to check the result sorted by *this* or *that*, perform some calculations, etc. - if that's so, maybe the simplest option is to

- create a table that contains columns returned by that query
- write a stored procedure that inserts the result into the table
- at the end of the procedure, use `UTL_MAIL` (or `UTL_SMTP`) and send yourself a mail, simply saying that processing is over
- connect to the database and select * from the table in order to review the result
- if the query result is simple, you could put it into the e-mail message body

Another option is to actually create the output file (using `UTL_FILE`) and send it by mail as an attachment.

Or, if you want to do it from the operating system level, you should still create the output file and use some *tool* that enables you to send mail.

Comment: I just need the counts to be sent to me by mail.

Comment: @Littlefoot, why not sending the email directly out of Oracle as described by JCBA ?

Comment: That would be the 3rd bullet,  @Maurice.

Comment: I'm trying the above code with no success. What am I missing?

Comment: I updated the script above and is now sending email "Counts on $DB_DBASE is" without the actual result of the query.